# Running python multiprocesses from a dynamic sql list

Tags: python, sql, loops, impala, multiprocess

Hi im trying to make my code a bit more dynamic and smart, to that end I want to call the functions I want to run through a dynamic list instead of having them hardcoded in. This will clean up the code and help with automatic rerun of failed scripts.

Below is a snippet of the code i have been working on.
i generally get this error when running it

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
 cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        f'''select distinct caller from {db}.log a where a.log_text like 'Failed:%' and a.log_time > DATE_TRUNC('DAY', NOW()) and caller not in (select caller from {db}.log a where a.log_text like 'Done' and a.log_time > DATE_TRUNC('DAY', NOW()))''')
    df = as_pandas(cursor)
    print('The following scripts will be rerun')
    print(df)

    c = df['caller']

    processes = []
    # Loop over failed scripts/modules
    for mod in (c):  
        print(f'Rerun of {c}')
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mod, args=(db,))
        time.sleep(10)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

The full traceback error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
> self.run()
> File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
> Process Process-2:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
> self.run()
> File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The `target` of a new subprocess must be a function object but you provide only the name of a function.

Comment: Can i convert the name to a function object of the same name ?

Comment: It would be better to find the function which is meant by the name or create a dict to map function names to objects. Where are the functions which should be called by the subprocess, same module as shown code, other module, scattered over multiple modules?

Comment: They are scattered in many different scripts/modules. Normally i just name them like 

"    for mod in (foo_1,foo_2......):    "

But for this code it will be different for each run what scripts or functions I want to call dependent on which might have failed during the first run.

Comment: Then a dictionary with function names as keys and function objects as values is the best way to solve this, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to the problem, and posting it here in case anyone could use it in the future.

Basically I use the getattr and importlib.import_module functions. Then I start them via a for loop.

So I use an sql to get the name of all failed module then load these module to a df list which is then iterated via a for loop which will start the failed module.

```
cursor.execute(
            f'''select distinct caller from {db}.sch_log_python a where a.log_text like 'Failed:%' and lower(caller) in ('st_%','ctrl_%','ar%') and a.log_time > DATE_TRUNC('DAY', NOW()) and caller not in (select caller from {db}.sch_log_python a where a.log_text like 'Done' and a.log_time > DATE_TRUNC('DAY', NOW()))''')
        df = as_pandas(cursor)
        print('The following scripts will be rerun')
        print(df)

        sch_log_func(caller, 'Rerun of failed scripts', db)

        c = df
        # Loop over failed scripts/modules
        for i in (c):
            cstr = c.to_string(index=False, header=False)
            print(f'Initialise ' + cstr)
            cstr = cstr.lower()
            print(cstr + ' Module to import')
            print('Trying to run ' + cstr)
            cls = getattr(importlib.import_module(cstr), cstr)
            cls(db)
            print(f'Started {cstr}')
```